# How to rename column in rails through terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, database-migration

I am unable to rename column through terminal

how to rename column in rails without writing anything inside migration file .I meant to say how we can rename column through terminal only.so please give me command so that i can do like that, not write anything inside migration file.

Comment: Keep in mind that in this case your migrations will not correspond to the actual database schema

Comment: why do you want to do this without migrations?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `ActiveRecord::Migration` methods explicitly from console:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.rename_column(:table_name, :old_column_name, :new_column_name)
```